Basic rules and advices to maintain purity while chanting a mantra or doing Upasana
How should one maintain purity while during daily mantra chanting . Should we take bath two times before each chanting a  day? Also do we also need to brush our teeth and apply good perfume during our Upasana. And what should be the dress code for the Upasana . Can we wear the same dress for two to three days at maximum with out properly washing ?

The most important thing while doing upasana or chanting mantra is that you need to maintain celibacy. No alcohol, non-veg or any kind of junk food for the time period you do upasana. You can do upasana whenever you want but I personally felt positive divine energy while chanting mantra at night before sleeping and early morning close to Brahmamuhurta time (generally 3:30-5:30am). Your soul needs to be pure which is more important than just focusing on cleaning the body.
Take shower if you feel stinky or if it helps you focus and feel fresh else taking shower is not important specially if you wake up early morning but do use the restroom and freshen up first.
You can also meditate for few minutes to calm your mind. It will also help you focus on chanting mantra.
You need to feel the mantra when you chant while focusing on God. Your mind will try to wander but just keep on bringing back your focus.
Brushing teeth or applying perfume is not important. Your devotion and faith is what really matters.
